# How to loop through data in a table and add it to a Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

The problem I am trying to solve using Excel VBA is with a table of information that I want to loop through and add to a Chart.

For example, the data file is in the following format:

```
 -696.710022 48 0 
 0 415.853546 2 1
 5 417.769196 2 1
 10 419.684845 2 1
 15 421.600464 2 1
 20 423.516113 2 1
 ......
 -602 48 0 
 0 371.893372 2 1
 5 373.851685 2 1
 10 375.810028 2 1
 15 377.768372 2 1
 20 379.726685 2 1
 ......
 -497.76001 48 0 
 0 323.194183 2 1
 5 325.189819 2 1
 10 327.185486 2 1
 15 329.181152 2 1
 20 331.176819 2 1
 ......
 etc.
```

In this file if Column 3 = "0" this is a header Row where by:

```
column 1 = location, 
column 2 = number of points at location, 
column 3 = header flag (i.e. "0")
```

The rest of the Rows are the data:

```
column 1 = X value,
column 2 = Y value,
column 3 = colour of points (i.e. 1 = green, 2 = blue, 3 = red).
```

I would like to run this in VBA because I have 40 or so of these charts to make. I have struggled making a script for VBA beyond importing a chart so I have not included my code here.

I really do appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to solve this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value in the second column of a header row shows the number of rows until the next header row (the sample data has ... after a while), this will set up the data, insert the charts, and color the points.

```
Sub DoCharts()
  Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long, iPt As Long, nPts As Long
  Dim rXVals As Range, rYVals As Range, rColor As Range
  Dim cht As Chart

  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
      If .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = 0 And Len(.Cells(iRow, 3).Text) > 0 Then
        ' value is zero and cell is not blank

        'define X and Y values
        nPts = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        Set rXVals = .Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Resize(nPts)
        Set rYVals = rXVals.Offset(, 1)
        Set rColor = rXVals.Offset(, 2)

        ' chart
        Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter, , .Cells(iRow, 1).Top).Chart

        ' clear existing series
        Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
          cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop

        ' add desired series
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
          .Values = rYVals
          .XValues = rXVals
        End With

        ' point color
        For iPt = 1 To nPts
          With cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(iPt)
            Select Case rColor.Cells(iPt)
              Case 1 ' green
                .MarkerForegroundColor = vbGreen ' use nicer colors, of course
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbGreen
              Case 2 ' blue
                .MarkerForegroundColor = vbBlue
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbBlue
              Case 3 ' red
                .MarkerForegroundColor = vbRed
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbRed
            End Select
          End With
        Next
      End If

      cht.HasLegend = False

      iRow = iRow + nPts
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

EDIT - Plot all in same chart.

I made minor changes. I still used the individual X values from each block of data. But I assumed that an entire series would have the same color formatting, so I formatted by series and not by point. I formatted each series as lines with markers, instead of just markers. I also used the first cell in each header row as the series name, so these are what distinguish the series in the legend. Finally I did not reposition the chart, but let Excel place it in the default position.

```
Sub DoOneChart()
  Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long, iPt As Long, nPts As Long
  Dim rXVals As Range, rYVals As Range, rName As Range
  Dim iColor As Long
  Dim cht As Chart

  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
      If .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = 0 And Len(.Cells(iRow, 3).Text) > 0 Then
        ' value is zero and cell is not blank

        'define X and Y values
        nPts = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        Set rXVals = .Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Resize(nPts)
        Set rYVals = rXVals.Offset(, 1)
        iColor = .Cells(iRow + 1, 3).Value
        Set rName = .Cells(iRow, 1)

        ' chart
        If cht Is Nothing Then
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart
          ' clear existing series
          Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
          Loop
        End If

        ' add desired series
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
          .Values = rYVals
          .XValues = rXVals
          .Name = "=" & rName.Address(, , , True)

          ' series color
          Select Case iColor
            Case 1 ' green
              .MarkerForegroundColor = vbGreen ' use nicer colors, of course
              .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbGreen
              .Border.Color = vbGreen
            Case 2 ' blue
              .MarkerForegroundColor = vbBlue
              .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbBlue
              .Border.Color = vbBlue
            Case 3 ' red
              .MarkerForegroundColor = vbRed
              .MarkerBackgroundColor = vbRed
              .Border.Color = vbRed
          End Select
        End With

      End If

      iRow = iRow + nPts
    Next
    cht.HasLegend = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. This is a fantastic solution to the problem. I note that a new Chart is created for each Series based on nPts. Seeing as they all share the same X Values is there a way to combine all of the X and Y values into 1 Chart?

Comment: @James - I've added a second procedure to plot all the data in one chart.